# Make cross domain json request to a server I dont have access to in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I want to make a request for a JSON object to a server, that I dont have access to. So I have to work with the JSON object I receive.

Since cross domain requests are not that easy (as I read) I would like to know if they are also working if you cannot modify the way the server responds.

What I read is, that JSONP is for cross platform, but you have to modify in some way the server-side response.

Comment: If the server doesn't support JSONP then you're out of luck

Answer (score 1):

If the webservice doesn't support JSONP, then you can't do it in javascript on the browser side. It is because of a security on the browsers. This security doesn't exist on your server, though.

You'll have to use a proxy, calling the webservice on your server (PHP or w/e).

For example:

- The javascript on your browser calls your server on the same domain.
- Your server on the same domain calls the webservice that doesn't support JSONP.
- Your server sends the JSON answer back to javascript on your browser.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in xml if the server returns XML?

Comment: Why not? You can handle XML in both JS and PHP.

Comment: Because I heard that xmlhttprequest is also not possible cross domain.